# NOT A GROUP BY EXPRESSION ADD NEW FIELD IN ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have next query:

```
SELECT NAME_TABLE.USER,
       TO_CHAR(NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN, 'DD/MM/YYYY') LAST_LOGIN,
       NAME_TABLE.SAILA,
       MAX(NAME_TABLE.INTENTS) INTENTS,
       NAME_TABLE.MAQ
FROM OWNER.MY_TABLE_NAME NAME_TABLE
WHERE NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN>=TO_DATE('22/02/2017' || ' 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
    AND NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN <= TO_DATE('22/02/2017' || ' 23:59:59', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
GROUP BY NAME_TABLE.USER,
         TO_CHAR(NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
         NAME_TABLE.SAILA,
         NAME_TABLE.INTENTS,
         NAME_TABLE.MAQ
ORDER BY NAME_TABLE.SAILA,
         NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN DESC;
```

I get next error:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

But execute next:

```
SELECT NAME_TABLE.USER,
       TO_CHAR(NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN, 'DD/MM/YYYY') LAST_LOGIN,
       NAME_TABLE.SAILA,
    (SELECT MAX(INTENTS)
     FROM OWNER.NAME_TABLE), NAME_TABLE.MAQ
FROM OWNER.MY_TABLE_NAME NAME_TABLE
WHERE NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN>=TO_DATE('22/02/2017' || ' 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
    AND NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN <= TO_DATE('22/02/2017' || ' 23:59:59', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
GROUP BY NAME_TABLE.USER,
         TO_CHAR(NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
         NAME_TABLE.SAILA,
         NAME_TABLE.INTENTS,
         NAME_TABLE.MAQ
ORDER BY NAME_TABLE.SAILA;
```

Any solution?

Why quit latest field execute nice?

And remplace

```
MAX(NAME_TABLE.INTENTS) INTENTS
```

For

```
(SELECT MAX(INTENTS) FROM OWNER.NAME_TABLE)
```

Why?

Update

```
SELECT USER, TO_CHAR(LAST_LOGIN, 'DD/MM/YYYY') LAST_LOGIN, SAILA, (SELECT MAX(INTENTS) FROM OWNER.NAME_TABLE, MAQ FROM OWNER.MY_TABLE_NAME 
WHERE LAST_LOGIN>=TO_DATE('22/02/2017' || ' 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AND LAST_LOGIN <= TO_DATE('22/02/2017' || ' 23:59:59', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
GROUP BY USER, TO_CHAR(LAST_LOGIN,'DD/MM/YYYY'), SAILA, INTENTS, MAQ ORDER BY SAILA;
```

Why quit of NAME_TABLE.FIELD TO FIELD no show errors?

Iam noob.

Thanks!

Comment: you don't need `NAME_TABLE.INTENTS` in `group by`

Comment: I have same error!

Comment: see this post http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64124/ora-00979-not-a-group-by-expression

Comment: Update post, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the `ORDER BY`.  Actually, you have *too many* columns in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT NAME_TABLE.USER,
       TO_CHAR(NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as LAST_LOGIN,
       NAME_TABLE.SAILA,
       MAX(NAME_TABLE.INTENTS) as INTENTS,
       NAME_TABLE.MAQ
FROM OWNER.MY_TABLE_NAME NAME_TABLE
WHERE NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN>=TO_DATE('22/02/2017' || ' 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
    AND NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN <= TO_DATE('22/02/2017' || ' 23:59:59', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
GROUP BY NAME_TABLE.USER,
         TO_CHAR(NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
         NAME_TABLE.SAILA,
         NAME_TABLE.MAQ
ORDER BY NAME_TABLE.SAILA,
         MAX(NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN) DESC;
```

So:

- `NAME_TABLE.INTENTS` should not be in the `GROUP BY` because it is an argument to `MAX()`.
- `NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN` cannot be in the `ORDER BY` because it is not in the `GROUP BY`.  You could put in `LAST_LOGIN`, but the column is defined in such a way that the ordering is awkward.  So, `MAX()` solves the problem.
- I would suggest changing the condition in the `WHERE` to:  `NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN >= DATE '2017-02-22' AND NAME_TABLE.LAST_LOGIN < DATE '2017-02-23`.  Much easier to read.

Comment: Better yet, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` should include `TRUNC(LAST_LOGIN)`, and `SELECT` should include `TO_CHAR(TRUNC(LAST_LOGIN), 'DD/MM/YYYY')`.

Comment: Thanks you so much!